# How to I exactly the position of a kivy text label on a canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, kivy, kivy-language

I have designed the following in figma. I have created a 500px x 500px window and a widget. I want to place the "in motion" text 160px from the left and 207px from the top.
[figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unrbW.png)

For images, that works well, but for text, it does not work at all. This is the code

```
class ScreenOne(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gif = Image(source='gifs/ring.gif', pos=(23, 191), size=(126, 119), anim_delay=0.1)
        self.gif0 = Image(source='gifs/test500.gif', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500), anim_delay=0.1)
        self.text1 = Label(text="1", pos=(77, 228), font_name="Inter-Bold", font_size=36)
        self.text2 = Label(text="in motion", pos=(160, 207), pos_hint=(0,0), size_hint=(0,0), font_name="Inter-Bold", font_size=64)
        self.add_widget(self.gif0)
        self.add_widget(self.gif)
        self.add_widget(self.text1)
        self.add_widget(self.text2)
```

The ring gif (gif) is perfectly located, but the text2 is completely off. See below:

Anyone any idea how to place the text labels exactly how I want them to be placed in Figma?

[Problem text in the wrong area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MttIr.jpg)

tried to use the labels pos_hint=(0,0), size_hint=(0,0) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `size` of the `text2` `Label` is the default size, giving it a width of 100. So the actual text will not fit in that size and gets centered about the actual `Label` size. So the result is that the `Label` is correctly positioned, but the text extends beyond that default size.

The fix is to adjust the `Label` size to correctly reflect what you would expect.

Try adding to your code:

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
''')
```

Then use `MyLabel` in place of `Label` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Excellent -> This worked. Thank you very much. I implemented it in the following way using the dimensions in Figma and added the size attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent -> This worked @John. Thank you very much. I implemented it in the following way using the dimensions in Figma and added the size attribute in the following way:

```
self.text2 = Label(text="in motion", pos=(160, 207), pos_hint=(0,0), size_hint=(0,0), size(296, 65), font_name="Inter-Bold", font_size=64)
```